# Downloading Image by URL using AsyncTask and using AnimationDrawable class to change images in intervals

Tags: java, android

Hi guys trying to implement AsyncTask here in my project, there seems to be no error shown by Android Studio either and have debugged to see if the bitmaps are downloaded and yes it is. I dont know what the problem is so here is my code.

My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView =findViewById(R.id.justAnImage);

        String[] strings = new String[2];
        strings[0] = "blah.com/sds.jpg";
        strings[1] = "blah.com/sds2.jpg";
        new AsyncDownloader(this,imageView).execute(strings);
    }

    public void StartAnimation(ImageView imageView, Bitmap[] bitmaps)
    {
        AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
        for (int i=0;i<bitmaps.length;i++) //replaced erroneous code-> (int i=0;i>=bitmaps.length;i++) 
        {
            animation.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(),bitmaps[i]),1000);
        }
        animation.setOneShot(false);

        imageView.setBackground(animation);

        // start the animation!
        animation.start();
    }
}
```

My Async downloader class

```
public class AsyncDownloader extends AsyncTask<String[],Void,Bitmap[]> {

    private Bitmap[] bitmapArray;
    private ImageView imageView;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public AsyncDownloader(MainActivity mainActivity,ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
        bitmapArray = new Bitmap[2];
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(String[]... strings) {

        for(int i=1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0][i]);
                bitmapArray[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            }  catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("DOWNLOAD ASYNC", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return bitmapArray;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] bitmapArray) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmapArray);
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray[0]);
        mainActivity.StartAnimation(imageView,bitmapArray);
    }
}
```

I cant find the problem here, debugging is so terrible in Android Studio. If any one could help, i shall be thankful.

EDIT 1: After suggestions from fellow stack guys, it is clear that the animation drawable is not working as desired and nonetheless there is no image showing up on the ImageView control.

EDIT 2: Code works after correcting the loop specified in the answer. Found an alternative to display images after certain interval. The code goes like this :

```
public void StartAnimation(final ImageView imageView, final Bitmap[] bitmaps)
{
    handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;

        public void run() {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps[i]);
            i++;
            if (i > bitmaps.length - 1) {
                i = 0;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1200);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1200);
}
```

Comment: You can use picasso library. Its quite easy and simple. Here is the [link](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: You can directly use glide or picasso library for this.

Comment: not looking for third party libraries folks

Comment: dear downvoter care to explain ? thanks!

Comment: "I cant find the problem here" - Why would you want a problem?

Comment: @MattBurner what is the issue you facing ?

Comment: @NabinBhandari There is no image showing in imageview... but the bitmap is getting displayed in console watch. There is no error shown, no runtime error which is why i am confused

Comment: issue is with your **StartAnimation** method

Comment: @KrishnaSharma what is the issue... i got no error there debugged it all through, man i wish i switched to xamarin

Comment: just change that method like this **public void StartAnimation(ImageView imageView, Bitmap[] bitmaps)
{
   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps[0]);
}** and then test.. once it started working we can fix animation

Comment: @KrishnaSharma i have tried and yes the image is getting loaded, but not working with animation why ?

Comment: Now you should modify the question accordingly to save vote down. because issue is something else that you mentioned in your question

Comment: @MattBurner is that true only first frame animation does work out of two ? for me only first frame does animate not the second one.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma tried changing the index to 1 and yes all bitmaps are loaded. Like this *imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps[1]);*

Comment: @MattBurner look at the updated answer, issue is with loop condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfect, except loop condition inside method `StartAnimation`.

**issue is with loop condition which is always false**.

To fix the issue change

**From**

```
for (int i = 0; i >= bitmaps.length; i++)
```

**To**

```
for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.length; i++)
```

Comment: Gives me error : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.setOneShot(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: My Bad, without testing posted as answer, hold on for a while

Comment: @MattBurner your code is perfect, issue is with your loop condition. Updated the answer, please look at it. I have verified by myself.

Comment: this is actually the answer, wow lost a ton of time on this.. also i have found an alternative to AnimationDrawable while i was ripping my hair off on this, i used Handler to change the image after 1200 secs. Visual Studio debugging has literally spoiled me, cant even simulate a loop in my head *Massive FacePalm*. Also i like to minimise the use of third party, you'll never no when the support ends especially when its open source.

Answer (score 0):

use [fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) or [picosso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library

these libraries automatically caching and managing memory.

it's easy to work with picosso and glide but fresco adds more features to developers.